# Seeking Research Opportunities

Tags: research-process, career-path, writing, international

I have been a teacher for 17 years and am looking to change careers. I earned a Master's Degree in International Relations with a concentration in East Asian Regional Affairs in 2004 and want to find a job with this.

I know I need to get my foot in the door, so in the mean time, I wanted to start to research and write.  I am also going back to school for a Master's Certificate.

How do I find companies/organizations to research and write for?  I really want to become noticed so I can get a job in International Relations.

Comment: Companies which may be interested in you doing *research* for them are usually called "Institute of something" or "Something Research center". In your case, that *something* will probably include the word "international".

Comment: Why thank you for your response.  I am not that ignorant.  I will be going back to school and am also interested in writing outside of my courses.  Hence, my question.

Comment: You could start by submitting pieces to newspapers and online blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, you just have to do the old Google search and linkedin trawl for everything you can think of. It's never easy, and there aren't any shortcuts.

I'd suggest asking around if you could volunteer your time with a smallish research organisation that fits nominally into your plans. It might be a local organisation, but you can always look abroad for centres that might value your native language skills.

It doesn't matter if you're just proofreading some of their work or helping sort files - it'll help get your foot in the door for future positions. More than that, most places will give you more responsibility as soon as they see you're trust worthy.

Lastly, when applying, you must always, **always** apply personally, and not with a blanket email. This isn't just about changing a few lines - take time to read about their research/organisation and say specifically what you can do to help. Talk about a particular project they're doing, and discuss how it aligns to your plans.